# Can we read data from a table if tablock is already applied on it in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am firing a select query on a table on which TABLOCK is already applied(Insertion is going on the table), I am not getting any result. Is it expected result? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on **which type** of lock is placed on the table.

If you have a **shared lock** from a `SELECT` operation, then yes - other `SELECT` statements can be executed against that table.

If you have an **exclusive lock** from a `DELETE`, `INSERT`, or `UPDATE` operation, then **no** other operations - not even `SELECT` queries - can be executed while the `TABLOCK` is in place.

Read more here:

- [Basics of Locking](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172909%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)
- [SQL Server Transaction Locking and Row Versioning Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)